# How to load styles from .scss files and react components to Storybook v7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sass, storybook

I'm trying to get storybook going for my project but it will not load the styles from my .scss files.
When I use inline styles in my components, it all works fine but not when the styles are imported.

The following images show the different output in storybook:
[Story with styles from .scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlbxT.png)
[Story with inline style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shWaG.png)

When reading on several threads it seems to be a "known issue" of sort but the solutions for everyone else does not seem to work for me.. Maybe it is because I'm not a front end developer originally, maybe it is something trivial I have missed and maybe I just have no clue what I'm doing.

The styles are all imported from a file next to the component:  `import * as styles from ./STYLESFILE.module.scss`.
This applies to all real components with all the depth and subfolders that entails.

TestComp.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import * as styles from "./test.module.scss";

export const TestThing: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return <div className={styles.thing}>test</div>;
};

export const TestInline: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return <div style={{ height: "50px", width: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" }}>test</div>;
};
```

test.module.scss

```
.thing {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I have tried to add support for this in main.ts as specified

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
const path = require("path");

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
    addons: ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials", "@storybook/addon-interactions", '@storybook/preset-scss',
      {
        name: '@storybook/addon-styling',
        options: {
          sass: {
            // Require your Sass preprocessor here
            implementation: require('sass'),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    framework: {
        name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
        options: {},
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: "tag",
    },

    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.resolve = config.resolve || {};
        config.resolve.alias = { src: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src") };

        config.resolve.modules = config.resolve.modules || [];
        config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"));

        return config;
    },
};
export default config;
```

I have read some suggestions to add things in the preview file, but that has not helped me.
My preview.tsx loos like this

```
import React from "react";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import "styles/global.module.scss";
import "../src/test.module.scss";

const preview: Preview = {
    decorators: [
        (Story) => (
            <Story />
        ),
    ],
};

export default preview;
```

Relevant parts of package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    ...
    "@parcel/resolver-default": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-svg-react": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/validator-typescript": "2.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.0",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.22",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.12.0",
    "@types/autobahn": "20.9.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.7",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.25",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.20",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.29.3",
    "concurrently": "7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.4.4",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "27.3.1",
    "jest-each": "27.4.6",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "27.5.1",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "jsdom": "20.0.3",
    "parcel": "2.8.3",
    "parcel-resolver-tspaths": "0.0.9",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "process": "0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "storybook": "^7.0.22",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "typescript": "4.9.3"
  },
```

All dependencies added with ^ are new for this branch where I try to add storybook.

In this project we are using typescript, react, parcel and node.

**==== things that did not work ====**
in main.ts, in webpackFinal I tried to add rules

first try:

```
config.module.rules.push({
            test: /.\.module\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/*'),
          });
```

second try:

```
config.module.rules.push({
          test: /.\.module\.scss$/,
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
          use: [
            {
                loader: "style-loader",
              options: {
                modules: {
                  namedExport: true,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: {
                  namedExport: true,
                },
              },
            }, 'sass-loader'
          ],
        });
```

both gave the same errors, and all of them seem to be "ModuleNotFoundError".
The output is aprox 2500 lines with 73 errors, and the last of them is this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './process-update' in '/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware'
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2022:28)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:817:13)
    at eval (eval at create (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:275:22)
    at eval (eval at create (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:28:14), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:448:22)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:118:11)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:689:25)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:893:8)
    at <anonymous> (/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:1013:5)
resolve './process-update' in '/...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware'
  using description file: /...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/package.json (relative path: ./process-update)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/process-update doesn't exist
      .module.scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/process-update.module.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        /...MY_PATH.../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/process-update doesn't exist

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```